# where can I learn about how do developer browser bookmarklets (language, framework, IDE, techniques etc)?

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

where can I learn about how do developer browser bookmarklets (language, framework, IDE, techniques etc)?  Perhaps they are more of a Javascript development thing?

To give examples of what I'm talking about see:

http://www.evernote.com/about/download/web_clipper.php

and

http://readitlaterlist.com/bookmarklets/

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.webreference.com/js/column35/ ?